# Flicking Scoreboard (Spigot)

Tags: java, minecraft, intellij-plugin

First of all I have some problems in my Scoreboard Plugin, For example:
If I join LocalHost Server(IP): Plugin really works well(no flash occurs in) but, otherwise, If I join connected domains(IP).. then I getting some flash every-time when I moving around the world[X Y Z]

I think I should change codes of "PlayerMoveEvent" and I knew ping difference makes flashing..
and It seems flash occur in MOVEMENT section.. in my opinions

Again, Every-time changing Player Location.. then got flashing every-seconds

I really wanna get feedbacks!

If you need MORE DETAILS Here(Video) : https://youtu.be/rKO36Lw73rc

```java
...

public class ScoreSidebar implements Listener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }


    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoinBoard(@NotNull PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        createBoard(event.getPlayer());

    }
    @EventHandler
    public void PlayerMoveEvent(@NotNull PlayerMoveEvent event) {
        createBoard(event.getPlayer());

    }

    public void createBoard(@NotNull Player player) {
        ScoreboardManager manager = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager();
        assert manager != null;
        Scoreboard board = manager.getNewScoreboard();

        Objective o = board.registerNewObjective("Scores", "dummy", ChatColor.AQUA + "§lSTATUS");
        o.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.SIDEBAR);

        Score score5 = o.getScore(" ");
        score5.setScore(6);

        Score score4 = o.getScore(ChatColor.YELLOW + "PLAYER: " +
                ChatColor.BOLD + Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() + ChatColor.WHITE + "/명");
        score4.setScore(5);

        Score score3 = o.getScore(ChatColor.GOLD + "MOVEMENT: " +
                ChatColor.WHITE + player.getLocation().getBlockX() + " " + player.getLocation().getBlockY()
                + " " + player.getLocation().getBlockZ() + "");
        score3.setScore(4);
        // Stream Location

        Score score2 = o.getScore(ChatColor.GRAY + "            " + " X | Y | Z ");
        score2.setScore(3);

        Score score1 = o.getScore("");
        score1.setScore(2);

        Score score = o.getScore(ChatColor.GRAY + "uhm... ");
        score.setScore(1);

        player.setScoreboard(board);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new scoreboard and replace the objective and all score, you have to keep the created one and update few score.

**How to do it ?**

Firstly, create the scoreboard when player join by keeping this part:

```java
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoinBoard(@NotNull PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        createBoard(event.getPlayer());
    }

    public void createBoard(@NotNull Player player) {
        ScoreboardManager manager = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager();
        assert manager != null;
        Scoreboard board = manager.getNewScoreboard();

        Objective o = board.registerNewObjective("Scores", "dummy", ChatColor.AQUA + "§lSTATUS");
        o.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.SIDEBAR);
        // here create default lines
        
        player.setScoreboard(board);

    }
```

Then, we will add line that will change :

```java
public void addLineToSb(Player p) {
   Scoreboard board = p.getScoreboard();
   Team myData = board.registerNewTeam("myData");
   myData.addEntry(ChatColor.BLACK + "");
   myData.setPrefix(ChatColor.RED + "My amazing data");
   obj.getScore(ChatColor.BLACK + "").setScore(14);
}
```

Now, we will want to update this line, so we will use something like this:

```java
public void update(Player p) {
   Scoreboard board = p.getScoreboard();
   board.getTeam("myData").setPrefix(ChatColor.RED + "My amazing data (2)");
}
```

And finally it's fine !

More informations : [official wiki](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/making-scoreboard-with-teams-no-flicker/)