# Scoreboard not updating even with scheduler

Tags: java, minecraft

This is the code but it doesnt update even with the scheduler and it gives me error in console and i tried to fix some stuff like before it didnt show the Damage dealt: and also didnt show the statistics but now it shows it but doesnt want to update

```
public class PlayerScoreboard {
    static Plugin p;

    public static void setPlugin(Plugin plugin) {
        p = plugin;
    }
    public static void showScoreboard(Player p) {
        ScoreboardManager manager = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager();
        if (manager == null) return;
        Scoreboard board = manager.getNewScoreboard();

        Objective objective = board.registerNewObjective("servername", "dummy", ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&e&lRAY'S &b&lSERVER"));
        objective.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.SIDEBAR);

        objective.getScore("————————————————").setScore(4);
        objective.getScore("").setScore(3);
        objective.getScore("§cDamage dealt: " +ChatColor.GREEN+p.getStatistic(Statistic.DAMAGE_DEALT)).setScore(2); // damage
        objective.getScore(" ").setScore(1);

        Team damage = board.registerNewTeam("damage");
        damage.addEntry(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "" + ChatColor.BLUE);
        damage.setPrefix(ChatColor.RED + "Damage dealt: " + ChatColor.GREEN + p.getStatistic(Statistic.DAMAGE_DEALT));


        p.setScoreboard(board);
        Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(Testing.getPlugin(Testing.class), () -> {
            try {
                updateDamage(p);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, 0L, 20L);
    }
    // call this when you need to update the damage
    public static void updateDamage(Player p) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Team team = p.getScoreboard().getTeam("damage");
        if (team == null) {
            System.out.println("damage Team was either deleted, or doesn't exist");
            throw new IllegalAccessException("Damage cannot be null");
        }

        team.setPrefix(ChatColor.RED + "Damage dealt: " + ChatColor.GREEN + p.getStatistic(Statistic.DAMAGE_DEALT));

    }
```

This is the error message in the console

```
[00:11:54] [Server thread/INFO]: [CoolPluginTest] [STDOUT] damage Team was either deleted, or doesn't exist
[00:11:54] [Server thread/WARN]: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Damage cannot be null
[00:11:54] [Server thread/WARN]:    at testing-1.0.jar//me.amxyargaming.testing.PlayerScoreboard.updateDamage(PlayerScoreboard.java:48)
[00:11:54] [Server thread/WARN]:    at testing-1.0.jar//me.amxyargaming.testing.PlayerScoreboard.lambda$showScoreboard$0(PlayerScoreboard.java:37)
[00:11:54] [Server thread/WARN]:    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:101)
[00:11:54] [Server thread/WARN]:    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHeartbeat(CraftScheduler.java:483)
[00:11:54] [Server thread/WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.b(MinecraftServer.java:1559)
[00:11:54] [Server thread/WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:479)
[00:11:54] [Server thread/WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1475)
[00:11:54] [Server thread/WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.x(MinecraftServer.java:1274)
[00:11:54] [Server thread/WARN]:    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:319)
[00:11:54] [Server thread/WARN]:    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

if you can help that would be great!

Comment: Does my answer fix your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it, and it works... with few edits.

When you unlog or if you scoreboard change, the task will continue to run ask create error. You currently make one task for each player. So, I suggest you to do this :

```java
@Override
public void onEnable() {
   // this will update for all online players.
   // So don't create for offline's one that do not longer have scoreboard
   Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, () -> {
      Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().forEach(PlayerScoreboard::updateDamage);
   }, 20, 20);
}
```

Then, if the team isn't found, you can just create a new one instead of throwing error. This can be better to prevent player to have empty scoreboard.

Also, you seems to never add the team's informations as score. I already made an answer about [how to make a good scoreboard that not flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69033362/10952503). You forget something like `objective.getScore(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "" + ChatColor.BLUE).setScore(mySlot);`

Finally, I don't know what's your server version but be carefull: you can reach the max length of scoreboard size. ([Spigot's thread about this](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/scoreboard-maximum-line-length.368663/))